# How to get last 30 items from multiple tables ordered by time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have like 3 tables to get info from them:

- articles
- posts
- pictures

All of this tables have 'created_at' column.

I want to get last 30 items ordered by created_at column throw sql query,
in the worst case i will have to eject 30 items from any table, and order it from array by php code.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: How would a `JOIN` help? You could perhaps devise some elaborate cross join that would let you identify the 30 most recent items across all three tables, but that's hardly the most elegant (or most efficient) approach. `JOIN` is not at all the right tool here.

Comment: my tables have some identical fields like (id, name, author_id), but there is also some not identical fields.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
(SELECT * FROM articles)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM posts)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM pictures)
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
LIMIT 30
```

This is untested, but should work.  Make sure to change "*" to whatever fields you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the past answers, and add a little bit of optimization here:

```
SELECT created_at, tbl, id, name, author_id FROM
  (SELECT created_at, "articles" as tbl, id, name, author_id 
   FROM `articles` ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30
   UNION 
  SELECT created_at, "posts" as tbl, id, name, author_id 
   FROM `posts` ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30
   UNION 
  SELECT created_at, "pictures" as tbl, id, name, author_id 
   FROM `pictures` ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30
  )
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30;
```

FWIW - this is untested and may contain stupid errors.

I'm first going to assume that created_at is indexed on all three tables.
I'm also going to restrict each table to only returning the 'last 30 items' so we're not ordering on a potentially huge derived table (in which we can't index).

So, the final 'order by' on the derived table is guaranteed to order <= 90 rows.
Much better than ordering the total union of 3 tables.

Comment: 'explain' is your friend here :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM articles UNION SELECT * FROM posts UNION SELECT * FROM pictures)
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 30
```

Almost certainly you will need to replace `*` with the list of fields common to both tables that you want to select (e.g., ID), and perhaps something to identify what type of object it was (e.g., `SELECT a, b, 'article' AS item_type`)

Be careful where you put your `WHERE` clauses. Ideally you can put one on each of the inner selects to limit what objects are included there, rather than putting one massive `WHERE` on the outside that must wait for the entire `UNION` operation to be performed first.

Comment: This would require that all 3 tables have the exact same columns, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think Lotus is right, if i have some not identical fields i can't do this query.

Comment: Be explicit about the columns to include instead of using * and you will avoid that problem.

Comment: This is precisely why I said "you will need to replace `*` with the list of fields common to both tables that you want to select". There is no such thing as a query that returns some fields for some rows and different fields for other rows. If you're hoping to get ALL the fields, the only way you can hope to do that is to `SELECT *, NULL AS x, NULL AS y, NULL AS z` filling in all the extra fields from all three tables, so you get a ton of columns with a lot of NULLs. That's quite ugly, as you can imagine, so avoiding it by only selecting what you need is best.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```
Select top 30 * from
(select acticles.created_at, ID 
from articles 
UNION
select posts.created_at, ID 
from posts 
UNION
select pictures.created_at, ID 
from pictures
ORDER BY 1)
```

Comment: I don't think that there is TOP function in mysql.